# PHP DOMDocument extract elements and create new document

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="preload" href="/_next/list.js" as="script">
    <!-- ... other link elemens -->
    <style data-styled="" data-styled-version="4.2.0"></style>
</head>
```

Task:

- extract all link and style tags from head and update href attributes with host path.
- create new html string element (piece of html) that we can output in our main html template.

PHP:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($stringBody);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$headItems = $xpath->query("//head/link[@rel='preload' or @rel='stylesheet'] | //head/style");

// now I want to create html string with updated attributes, but I'm lost here..
$head = new DOMDocument();
foreach ($headItems as $headNode) {
    $headNode->setAttribute('href', $host . $headNode->getAttribute('href'));
}
$links = $head->saveHTML($headNode);
echo $links; // echo html link tags
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
<?php

$host = 'example.com';

$stringBody = '<head>
    <link rel="preload" href="/_next/list.js" as="script">
    <!-- ... other link elemens -->
    <style data-styled="" data-styled-version="4.2.0"></style>
</head>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($stringBody);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$headItems = $xpath->query("//head/link[@rel='preload' or @rel='stylesheet'] | //head/style");

$links = [];

foreach ($headItems as $headNode) {
    if ($headNode->hasAttribute('href')) {
        $headNode->setAttribute('href', $host . $headNode->getAttribute('href'));
    }
    $links[] = $headNode->ownerDocument->saveHTML($headNode);
}

print_r($links);
```

Output

```html
Array
(
    [0] => <link rel="preload" href="example.com/_next/list.js" as="script">
    [1] => <style data-styled="" data-styled-version="4.2.0"></style>
)
```

Comment: How to return results without  html, head tags?

Comment: You mean only a list of the tags `<link rel="preload"`? or the urls only?

Comment: Yes, list of the tags